# Should a reusable React component written in Typescript shipped as JavaScript with type definitions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I've several React components which I want to make reusable. They are written with TypeScript. My question is now, how such Component libraries which a written with TypeScript are usually shipped?

I want to make it usable also for JavaScript only projects. Should the dist folder contain a compiled .js-file, along with type definitions? So both, TypeScript and JavaScript projects can use my React components.

What seems to be a bit odd is, that I've written it in TypeScript, then I compile it to JavaScript and make it compatible with TypeScript again by delivering some type definitions.

Comment: Why does it seem odd?

Comment: It's like a book which was written in English (TypeScript) and then translated to German (JavaScript). Some people in Germany are expats and don't understand German. Now they should use the German version of the book with a German to English dictionary (type definitions). I think the expats would rather like the original English book.

Comment: No, it's not the same at all. In your example, nuances of the language can get lost in translation. That CANNOT happen in what you're actually talking about. Typescript is just meta information about JavaScript code. You publish the JavaScript code and the meta information (types) along with it. The consumer of the library doesn't care what it's written in, all they care about is if they can use it in their project. It's the entire reason why [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) exists.

Comment: So the conclusion is, that's how it should be done?

Comment: Yeah, I like [rollup typescript](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/typescript) to generate my definition files